# C++ to Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

Needing help translating this c++ code into Pep/9 assembly language. Quite stuck on where to even begin.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int width;
int length;
int perim;

int main() {
    cin >> width >> length;
    perim = (width + length) * 2;
    cout << "w = " << width << endl;
    cout << "l = " << length << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "p = " << perim << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All you need to accomplish is input, addition, doubling, and output.  So, look for those individual capabilities, then combine them into a program.

Answer (score 2):

"Needing help translating this c++ code into Pep/9 assembly language." - Get your compiler to do it for you (that's what compilers *do* after all). All the major compilers have options to generate ASM and then stop.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I apologize for any confusion on my part - I am very new to this topic. I am trying to access the capability to do this within CodeBlocks but am having some trouble. Will continue the search based on this suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: The PEP/9 is an invented CPU that works via a simulator as a tool for learning about computers. There is no C++ compiler for it.